# Reverse Geocode using API Key for Google Sheet

Tags: reverse, geocode

I need to get a working JSON script for Google Sheet to get "FOMATTED_ADDRESS" for more than 5,000 GPS coordinates.

[image: 1]

I am no expert in JSON nor Javascipt.. I only need a simple script that works in Sheet. All I have tried I get an error in the result of the query..
Can somebody help?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are not a developer, then the easiest way is to use ready-made add-ons available in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/sheets%20maps).